# datatables: how to change the value of a cell on spacebar?

Tags: datatables

I would like to change the value of a cell in datatables. The idea is to switch between pre-set values when pressing spacebar on a focussed cell. But i am not sure how to implement this.

I am initializing DataTable in the following way.

```
var table = $('#data-table').DataTable();

var keys = new $.fn.dataTable.KeyTable( table );
```

Anybody has a suggestion?

Comment: The problem will be focusing a table cell. There's no way to focus a table cell if its just a plain HTML table.

Comment: well, what I meant with "on a focussed cell", is when it has been selected with KeyTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears that the documentation of KeyTables 2.0 is not updated yet. I managed to do it in the following way:

```
var table = $('#data-table').DataTable();
var keys = new $.fn.dataTable.KeyTable( table );

table.on( 'key', function ( e, datatable, key, cell, originalEvent ) {
    if (key == 32) { #32 for spacebar
        var currentStatus = cell.data();
        switch(currentStatus) {
            case 'p':
                cell.data('f');
                $(cell.node()).removeClass('status_p').addClass('status_f');
                break;
            case 'f':
                cell.data('h');
                $(cell.node()).removeClass('status_f').addClass('status_h');
                break;
            case 'h':
                cell.data('p');
                $(cell.node()).removeClass('status_h').addClass('status_p');
                break;
            default:
                cell.data('p');
                $(cell.node()).attr('class','').addClass('status_p');
        }
    }
});
```